# pandas profiling with dask-dataframe. IndexError

Tags: python, index-error, dask-dataframe, pandas-profiling, eda

I get an IndexError (`IndexError: only integers, slices (:), ellipsis, nmpy.newaxis and integer or bolean arays are valid indices`) while pandas profiling with dask.
data: 290170 x 55

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
df = dd.read_csv("covtype.data").compute()

df.columns = ["Elevation", "Aspect", "Slope", "Horizontal_d_to_hydrology", "vertical_d_to_hydrology", "Horizontal_Distance_To_Roadways", "Hillshade_9am", "Hillshade_Noon", "Hillshade_3pm", "Horizontal_Distance_To_Fire_Points", "Rawah Wilderness Area","Neota Wilderness Area", "Comanche Peak Wilderness Area", "Cache la Poudre Wilderness Area", "2702", "2703", "2704", "2705", "2706", "2717", "3501", "3502", "4201", "4703", "4704", "4744", "4758", "5101", "5151", "6101", "6102", "6731", "7101", "7102", "7103", "7201", "7202", "7700", "7701", "7702", "7709", "7710", "7745", "7746", "7755", "7756", "7757", "7790", "8703", "8707", "8708", "8771", "8772", "8776", "Cover_Type"]

ProfileReport(df)
```

Comment: since you call `.compute()`, I think `df` is a pandas dataframe, not a dask dataframe

Answer (score 0):

*Quick fix*: following [Issue #991](https://github.com/ydataai/pandas-profiling/issues/911), you can change line **#13** in `utils_pandas.py`, just like [ieaves](https://github.com/ieaves) suggested.

From: `w_median = (data[weights == np.max(weights)])[0]`

To: `w_median = (data[np.where(weights == np.max(weights))])[0]`

Also: take a look at [Paul H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552748/paul-h) comment, maybe the dask dataframe is incompatible.